# How to reduce the width of the lengthy data in html css without affecting the data with smaller length?

Tags: android, html, css, angularjs, cordova

I am displaying some user details Name, phone number mobile number, e-mail, etc in my angular 5 mobile app.

Those details are gettinggotten from the response.., i I am using to swipe to view the each member's information.I

I am using table tag tag to display each member'informationmember's information in a table cell  (Anyhow, the table will not be visible in the app's screen). Now the problem i am facing is

I am getting some lengthy email addresses from the response  (say for eg.,abcdefghijklmnopqrsrsrsr@gmail.comabcdefghijklmnopqrsrsrsr@gmail.com i.e, more than 23 characters) Since it's too lengthy.., It'sit's not fitting in the single view,view; it's crossing the screen and touching the other member's detail view.

If I try word-wrap: break-word for email email alone., It breaks all the small e-mail address too.., (for eg., arunprs@gmail.comarunprs@gmail.com). Now I need to break only the lengthy email addresses., Notnot the small oneones.

The small email address should display as such it is. How can I do it? Please Help me friends.., Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek I know that I didn't asked the question in the right manner., Right now I am in hurry, so that I asked in this way. Please kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine writing out a function or similar to change the font size proportionally to the length of emails, or alternatively maybe show first 5 letters of the email and have a button to reveal the rest (as a last resort).

Edit (after `word-break` idea):

About `word-break: break-all;` I would recommend to use jQuery (if not yet!) to work out an 'optimal' length number (something like 23 chars I'd imagine) so: `if length > 23 then add css-property word-break: break-all;`

Comment: having the button here is not allowed in my side. I just need to wrap the lengthy email address in a single screen, without going outside the current view

Comment: @Arun about `word-break: break-all;` I would recommend to use jQuery (if not yet!) to work out an 'optimal' length number (something like 23 chars I'd imagine) so: `if length > 23 then add css-property word-break: break-all;`

Comment: How can i do that?.. The reason why I am asking this to you bcoz., I am entirely new to this angular css nd HTML. So please guide me further

Answer (score 0):

I have already used in my project, like this:

```
h4{
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    align-items:center;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

OR you can use the textarea, If you want treat textarea as input type then you can change its look & feel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **word-break: break-all;** CSS property. It will only break the email addresses which are longer in length and will keep the short emails intact.